# PayPal REST API C# Mobile Express Checkout

Tags: c#, api, rest, paypal

I want to use PayPal Mobile Express Checkout because it has a mobile site. I cannot work out how to get the REST API to use the Mobile PayPal Express Checkout.

With the Classic API it is possible to set a parameter:

```
METHOD=SetExpressCheckout
```

And then the cmd parameter to use the Mobile Express Checkout:

```
https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_mobile-express-checkout&useraction=commit&token=<TokenValue>
```

Has anyone been able to get the REST API to use Mobile Express Checkout?